# Calculating mass, having a density (as a function) and a volume

Tags: integration, density-function

Trying to find a simple solution, there is a lot of info online, but I do not see what I need.

**M = V*d**

I have V, for instance, **V = 3000**

I have d as a function, for instance, **0.5(y + 3)(8 - y) in grams per cubic cm.**

How to find a mass though integration, having a density as a function.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined the total volume, but not specifically what volume of $3000$ you are interested in.  The mass is $\int d dV$  Once you specify the limits of integration, the integral can be done (assuming they are simple enough).  Contrast a volume near $y=5.5$ where the density is about $15$ with a volume near $y=8$ where the density is very small.

Comment: thanks! Sorry, I am very new to this topic. I guess I am interested in ALL volume (not sure if I give you the right answer though). I need to calculate the mass of a metal plate. I guess I need to integrate from 0 to .......? Also, what ρ? Pi? D and V are clear. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Rho ($\rho$) is the same as $d$ in your question.

Comment: @John:  I used $\rho$ for your $d$ and have fixed it.  Yes, I understand you are interested in the total mass.  You need to integrate over the volume of the plate. If the plate is thin in $y$ the density won't change much so you can just use the average value.  Otherwise you need to integrate in $y$.  In $x$ and $z$ there is not variation in density, so you can just multiply the $y$ integral by the area in $x$ and $z$.

Comment: Folks, can somebody navigate me to a right example, I do not know how to do this.